# Suppress warnings for missing @Override annotation in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, warnings

I have warnings for the missing `@Override` annotation enabled by default in Eclipse, but for a couple of classes I'd rather have it disabled.

Is there a way to do this? Intuitively one would expect something like `@SuppressWarnings("override")` but that is of course not supported.

Comment: Why are you wanting to suppress the warnings?  They're useful, and using them costs nothing.

Comment: There's @SuppressWarnings("all") which disables the override warning too, but that's likely too drastic.

Comment: There are situations where the ability to suppress @Override warnings is useful, e.g. GWT does not support Object#clone() [1], thus overriding this method in any class would give a warning.

[1] https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=1843

Comment: You should turn your comment into an answer @kiheru.  It's not perfect and it can obviously suppress valid warnings, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: @deinocheirus, on example you might want to add to your answer is a method that is in the java7 version of an interface but not in java6.  So if you add the `@Override` it breaks java6 backwards compatibility.  For example: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/CommonDataSource.html#getParentLogger()

Answer (score 0):

In *eclipse -> windows -> preferences*, select *java -> compiler -> **Errors/warnings***

type override in the search bar then for "missing @overriden annotation" set level to ignore.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: @deinocheirus it can be made on project, not the workspace. If this is not what you were asking for, the answer to your question is 'No'

Answer (score -4):

You should annotate all methods with @Override

or when you don´t want to annotate with this annotation, than you should edit compiler settings in

eclipse to not show a warning when you don´t annotate with @Override.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: You can´t disable the warning for a couple of classes. You only can change compiler settings for a whole project.